# How to get the modified time of a remote file in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to get the last modified date of a log file on a remote Windows server 2008/2012 with a batch script.
I am connecting to the machine using "net use", and able to see if the file exists.

```
net use \\X.X.X.X /user:%USERNAME% %PASSWORD%
if exist "\\X.X.X.X\\C$\\Temp\\LogFiles\\abcd" (
    echo ABCD file exists on the server
) else (
    echo ABCD file does NOT exist on the server
)
```

Also, I am able to get the last updated time of a local file using forfiles:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('"forfiles /m MyLocalAbcd /c "cmd /c echo @file was last modified at @ftime" "') do set modif_time=%%i
echo %modif_time%
```

However, I am not able to get the modified time of the remote file. I tried to provide the complete path - forfiles /M "\X.X.X.X\C$\Temp\LogFiles\abcd" - or even providing the path to the option P of forfiles, but it is not finding the file.

Is there an easy way to get the modified date/time of the remote file?
Also, I am wondering if there is a way to tail the last n lines of the same file with a Windows built-in command.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `dir`.

Or use a for loop differently.

```
for %%A in (\\server\C$\Temp\LogFiles\abcd) do echo %%~tA
```

A working example if pasted into a command prompt.

```
for %A in (\\127.0.0.1\C$\windows\win.ini) do echo %~tA
```

To the other question you sneeked in

`more +50` skips first 50 lines.

This VBScript does what you want.

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
Set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
With rs
    .Fields.Append "LineNumber", 4 

    .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
    .Open
    LineCount = 0
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        LineCount = LineCount + 1
        .AddNew
        .Fields("LineNumber").value = LineCount
        .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
        .UpDate
    Loop

    .Sort = "LineNumber ASC"

    If LCase(Arg(1)) = "t" then
        If LCase(Arg(2)) = "i" then
            .filter = "LineNumber < " & LCase(Arg(3)) + 1
        ElseIf LCase(Arg(2)) = "x" then
            .filter = "LineNumber > " & LCase(Arg(3))
        End If
    ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "b" then
        If LCase(Arg(2)) = "i" then
            .filter = "LineNumber > " & LineCount - LCase(Arg(3))
        ElseIf LCase(Arg(2)) = "x" then
            .filter = "LineNumber < " & LineCount - LCase(Arg(3)) + 1
        End If
    End If

    Do While not .EOF
        Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value

        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

To use

Filter reads and writes standard in and standard out only. These are only available in a command prompt.

```
filter <inputfile >outputfile
filter <inputfile | other_command
other_command | filter >outputfile
other_command | filter | other_command
```

**Cut**

```
filter cut {t|b} {i|x} NumOfLines
```

Cuts the number of lines from the top or bottom of file.

```
t - top of the file
b - bottom of the file
i - include n lines
x - exclude n lines
```

**Example**

```
filter cut t i 5 < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```